# problem solving logarithmic equation and reaching an equivalence

Tags: logarithms

ok so i've had a problem trying to simplify the  $\ln\left[ \sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{a^2}} + \frac{u}{a} \right]$ and this is supposed to be equal to :  $\ln [ \sqrt{a^2+u^2} + u ]$

how is this posible ?? i've tried to solve this for more than 2 hours and couldn't get to this equivalence. any suggestions ?

Comment: They are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that you got this as the result of an (indefinite) integration, and $a$ is a constant. Let $a$ be positive. We are taking the ln of
$$\frac{1}{a}\left(\sqrt{u^2+a^2}+u\right).$$
Taking the ln, we get
$$\ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+u\right)-\ln a.$$
But $\ln a$ is a constant, so can be absorbed into the constant of integration.

In more detail, if
$$\ln\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{a^2}}+\frac{u}{a}\right)+C$$
is the answer to an indefinite integral problem, where $C$ is an arbitrary constant, then
$$\ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+u\right)+D$$
is a correct answer to the same problem.

This sort of thing happens a lot, particularly with trigonometric functions. As a simple example, if $\sin^2 x+C$ is "the" answer to an indefinite integration problem, then so is $-\cos^2 x+C'$.

Comment: yes this is true, thnx  but  the integration requests of me to  que rid  of  `- ln q`and  i  don´t  know  how  this is posible,  the  integration excercise  is  this: integral of:  ` u^2 * sqrt(a^2+u^2)du `  and im having trouble with  the final part  of this  integration  which is getting rid  of  ` - ln (a)`

Comment: That gets absorbed into the constant of integration. Or if you are doing a definite integral, the "ugly" version and the nicer version can each be used, since they are both antiderivatives of the function you were integrating.  The two functions are not equal, but they differ by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln x$ is injective so, if $\ln x=\ln y\implies x=y$. So, the following should hold true:\begin{align}
\sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{a^2}}+\frac{u}{a}=\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+u\end{align}

However, simply plugging in $u=1, a=2$ gives us

\begin{align*}
&\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{4+1}+1\\
&\implies \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}+\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{5}+1\\
&\implies \sqrt{\frac{5}{4}}=\sqrt{5}-\frac{1}{2}\\
&\implies \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}=\frac{2\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\\
&\implies \sqrt{5}=2\sqrt{5}-1
\end{align*}
which is false.

Hence they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& \ln\left( \sqrt{1+\frac{u^2}{a^2}} + \frac{u}{a} \right) = \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{a^2}+\frac{u^2}{a^2}} + \frac u a\right) =  \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{a^2+u^2}{a^2}} + \frac u a\right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \ln\left(\frac {\sqrt{a^2+u^2}} a  + \frac u a\right) = \ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{a^2+u^2}+u} a\right) = \ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+u^2} + u\right) - \ln a
\end{align}

If this is viewed as a function of $u$, then $a$ is constant, so it's
$$
\ln\left(\sqrt{a^2+u^2} + u\right) + \text{constant}
$$